# Include new Javascript into wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I recently started working on a wordpress site.
I have the woo commerce plugin working and he mystile theme. SO far so good!
However the gallery sucks!

I am trying to fiddle aroundwith it, but do not know my way around wordpress too well.

Question:

How do I add a line into the header?
Say for the single product, I would want to include a Javascript file. Do you know how I would do that?
What file do I augment?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Bo

Comment: What line? What header? What file? DETAILS MAN DETAILS!

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a `javascript` file to the `wordpress theme`, you have 2 alternative:

Suppose we have a `jquery.js` inside the directory root of the theme.

**Method A)**

Open  `header.php` file in wordpress theme. Add this inside `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/jquery.js"></script>
```

---

**Method B)**

Open `functions.php` file in wordpress theme:

Search something like `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blahblah' );`, 
If exist, find a function with `blahblah` name and add this code inside it:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'jquery', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery.js', array(), '1.8.3', false );
```

Otherwise: You should add a `function` and `add_action` method:

```
function scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'jquery', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery.js', array(), '1.8.3', false ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_styles' );
```

Note: Replace `jquery` string with your file name so.